# If $\|T\| < 1$, then $I-T$ is invertible and $\|(I-T)^{-1}\| \leq (1-\|T\|)^{-1}$

Tags: functional-analysis

This is a hint in my functional analysis book, and I can`t uncipher it. They give as additional information that $T \in B(X)$ where $X$ is a normed linear space. 
I think $X$ should be a Banach Space, but the hint is quite explicit.

Comment: Hint: try Riemann series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}T^k$.

Comment: Nope, its the Neumann series, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series, not "John von N." but "Carl N." some 60 years earlier.

Answer (score 8):

By the hypothesis the [Neumann series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series) $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty T^n$ is absolutely convergent so convergent and we have

$$(I-T)\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty T^n=\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty T^n\right)(I-T)=I$$
so $I-T$ is invertible and its inverse is $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty T^n$, moreover we have
$$\left\|\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty T^n\right\|\le\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \|T\|^n=\frac{1}{1-\|T\|}$$

**Remark** In the previous inequality we use the continuity of the norm.

Comment: I modified your TeX code a bit, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @dtldarek Thanks.

Comment: The series has a name, for historical reasons, otherwise its just a geometric series in an operator algebra. Added wiki-link for it.